# Send image from android - receives rotated picture on server

Tags: php, android

I am trying to write an android app that takes a picture and saves it to a server. The problem is that every picture I take is rotated with -90 degrees when saved on the server. Any idea how I can rotate the picture in php or why it ends up being rotated?

This is how my php file looks like:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "photos/";
    $img = $_REQUEST['base64'];
    $name=$_REQUEST['ImageName'];


    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($img);

$success = file_put_contents($file_path.$name, $binary); 

if($success === false) {
    echo "Couldn't write file";
} else {
    echo "Wrote $success bytes";
}
echo $name;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with image orientation.

Try this

```
 $exif = exif_read_data($file_path.$name);
            $ort = $exif['IFD0']['Orientation'];
            switch($ort)
            {

                case 3: // 180 rotate left
                    $image->imagerotate($file_path.$name, 180, -1);
                    break;


                case 6: // 90 rotate right
                    $image->imagerotate($file_path.$name, -90, -1);
                    break;

                case 8:    // 90 rotate left
                    $image->imagerotate($file_path.$name, 90, -1);
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a server side issue, every smartphone can apply a different orientation to the camera images.
When you receive the image you have to access to its metadata (exif data si the exact name) to verify its rotation and other properties. Then you should apply to the picture the transformations you need.

This should be a good startpoint to read exif data with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php